# Blender in ElementaryOS installed from most recent 2.79 build

Tags: python

I installed most recent blender from ppa:thomas-schiex/blender to get the most recent blender version. Starting blender now results in crash. Running blender inside terminal from directory /usr/lib/blender leaves me with

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

So far I found out that I need to install python sources. To find them I installed Synaptic Package manager and searched for them and couldnt find them. Therefor I also ran

```
apt-get source python
```

I still get that error when I start blender from Terminal. 
Perhaps anyone knows how to resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

Others seemed to have a similar issue as well but couldnt resolve it: [Blender with system python failing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42860/blender-with-system-python-failing)

Here is my solution also posted over there:

All right... I had the same error appearing today and I have been able to solve it. It's been pretty easy. After removing blender and installing blender from ppa:thomas-schiex/blender There were some files still around.
To make sure everything works try:

```
sudo apt-get purge blender
cd /usr/lib
sudo rm -r blender
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thomas-schiex/blender
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install blender
```

Since everything is purged AND manually removed from versions installed manually it should be fine now. Have fun  :)